# How primitive long and int comparison happens in Java

Tags: java

```
long l = 1234;
int i  = 1234;

if (l == i) {
  System.out.println("equals");
} else {
  System.out.println("not equals");
}
```

My question is are they compared as `int` or `long`?

I think both are int unless we specify

```
long l = 1234L;
```

If someone has a deeper understanding then please explain.

Comment: My guess is `i` is implicitly cast to long and then compared to your `l`.

Comment: `l` is a `long`, then the comparison is between two longs. The longest type is the one used. Read JLS about these basic things.

Comment: `l` is of type `long` because it is declared that way. In the comparison expression, the `int` value is promoted to `long` so two `long` values are compared.

Comment: @xander don't guess, read the spec to find out what it does.

Comment: remove "My question is are they compared as int or long?" from the code section and add it to the body

Answer (score 6):

Since one of the operands of the `==` operator is `long` (`l`) It compares two `long`s after converting `i` to `long`.

Related JLS quotes:

[**15.21.1. Numerical Equality Operators == and !=**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21.1)

> If the operands of an equality operator are **both of numeric type**, or one is of numeric type and the other is convertible (§5.1.8) to numeric type, **binary numeric promotion is performed on the operands** (§5.6.2).
>
> If the promoted type of the operands is int or long, then an integer equality test is performed.

**[5.6.2. Binary Numeric Promotion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2)**

> Otherwise, **if either operand is of type long, the other is converted to long**.

Comment: There's no dupetarget for something this basic?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder sometimes it's just easier to answer than find the dupe :/

Comment: Thanks. So, Auto Promotion takes place

Answer (score 2):

It has to be `int` to `long`, since some big long value can not be converted to int value without losing precision.